# How to pass id to the form action using javascript in Laravel?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to update and delete data using forms with laravel but I cannot send the id using javascript. These are the scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", ".edit_modal", function () {
        var data_id = $(this).data('id');
        var data_name = $(this).data('name');
        $(".form-group #edit_name").val(data_name);
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", ".delete_modal", function () {
        var data_id = $(this).data('id');
    });
</script>
```

And these are the forms inside a modal

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('sale.update'), INSERT ID HERE }}" role="form">
<div class="modal-body">
    @csrf()
    @method('PATCH')
    <input type="hidden"  name="edit_id" id="edit_id"/>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('sale.destroy'), INSERT ID HERE }}" role="form">
    @csrf()
    @method('DELETE')
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="delete()" value="Yes">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: By `I cannot send the id using javascript.` What does it Mean?? You can't POST `id` Value using AJAX??

Comment: @JensonMJohn it means I don't know how. I tried to use hidden input and made its value $id but the form doesn't recognize it

Comment: I don't see any `value` attribute in Your Hidden input.

Comment: I shorten the code but it's there. When I make it `type="text"` instead of `hidden` I can see the id but I don't how to bring that id up the form

Answer (score 0):

`{{route('sale.update')}}` are executed at server. When it got to the browser, it's already become like this `action="siteaddress.com/sales/123"`. You can change it with Regex.

I can't give you complete code with just the information in the question, but you said that you can change an input inside the form already, so try something like this:

```js
let data_id = $(this).data('id');
let form = $(this).closest('form');
//change the regex according to your actual route
let url = form.prop('action').replace(/(\/sales\/)\d+/, '$1' + data_id);
form.prop('action', url);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know what happened but the modal doesn't show after I entered your code but I have new discovery. I can add `$("#editSaleForm").attr("action", "{{ route('sale.update', "1") }}");` this to give the form new action but I don't know what's the format for update link in laravel

Comment: The `{{...}}` are executed by Blade at server, putting it in JS won't do anything. Can you show full structure (rendered HTML, not Blade template) of the modal, the element you use to summon it, the element where you get id from, etc... and the relevant scripts?